# HTML webpage getting element

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

Following is my script....

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

page = requests.get("https://niftyinvest.com/max-pain/ULTRACEMCO?expiry=25JAN2023")

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
#print(soup.prettify)
all_tags = []
for element in soup.select('h6'):
    all_tags.append(element.text)

print(all_tags)
```

And I have following output....

['Max Pain\n                                        for ULTRACEMCO\n                                        is\n                                        7000 info\n', '7000 CE ', '\n 159.90\narrow_drop_down ni-icon\n                                                    \n-29.65\n', 'Open Interest', '139,700\n                                                    arrow_drop_up ni-icon9,400\n                                                ', '7000 PE ', '154.90\n      arrow_drop_up ni-icon\n                                                     13.35', 'Open Interest', '101,700\n                                                    arrow_drop_up ni-icon\n                                                     23,100', 'What is Max Pain?', 'Calculating Max Pain', 'How can a trader benefit?']

[Program finished]

Here I want output as.....

ULTRACEMCO  7000
(which is in very first line of my output)

Can anyone help plz...

Comment: `list.sort` returns always `None`. Try `sorted(a)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read [the Python documentation of the `sort` method of a list](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html). Check the contents of `a` after calling .sort().

```
sort(*, key: None = ..., reverse: bool = ...) -> None
sort(*, key: (int) -> SupportsRichComparison, reverse: bool = ...) -> None

Sort the list in ascending order and return None.

The sort is in-place (i.e. the list itself is modified) and stable (i.e. the order of two equal elements is maintained).

If a key function is given, apply it once to each list item and sort them, ascending or descending, according to their function values.

The reverse flag can be set to sort in descending order.
```

If you want the sorted list is a separate, new list, do:

```
sorted_list = sorted(a)
```

Comment: Sir I'm trying to remove rows for a particular symbol in above df by following script.....  new_df1 = df[df.symbol != 'MARUTI']     now how to write it for more than one symbol in above df let's say for DIXON, DRREDDY, LTI, MRF.

Comment: Use Pandas' `isin()` in combination with ~ (tilde) as not-operator. Like this: `skip_list = ['DIXON', 'DRREDDY', 'LTI', 'MRF']; df[~df.symbol.isin(skip_list)]`

Comment: Not working for me.